# Output of the text extracted from tesseract ocr

Tags: python, ocr, tesseract, python-tesseract

I am using google tesseract to extract text from images. I have a folder where I have some images and I wanted to store the extracted text in form of a text file. The results are okay but there is some red boxes shown in the output .txt file.

Here is my code for text extraction from a folder

```
import cv2
import pytesseract as pt
import os

custom_config = "--oem 3 --psm 6"

path ="/home/rakshit/Documents/textextraction/croped/82092117"

textBox = []
for filename in os.listdir(path):
    head = os.path.split(filename)
    file_name = head[1].split('_',1)[0]

    imagePath = os.path.join(path, filename)
    img = cv2.imread(imagePath)
    text = pt.image_to_string(image, config = custom_config)
    textBox.append(text)

finalPath = f"/home/rakshit/Documents/textextraction/outputText/detected/{file_name}.txt"

with open(finalPath, 'w') as f:
    for t in textBox:
        f.write(t)
        f.write("\n")
```

The output text is something like this:
[Output text file image](https://i.stack.imgur.com/WgiCB.png)

Can someone tell me what are these boxes have appeared in the output text file?
Thanks in advance for any time you have devoted to this problem.

Answer (score 0):

Sharing a screen image of text file is not a good manner. But I guess it is the [page break](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Page_break).